# click event on select option element doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know I have to change the `id` into a `val` but how??? any idea? sorry, It might be so easy for you guys but not for me:-)

- each option scrollTo a specific tag, but on click doesn't work

http://jsfiddle.net/9w0L7fxb/

```js
var body = $('html, body');

$('#London').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    body.animate({
        scrollTop: slideMap.offset().top - 63
    }, 'slow');

    return false;
});

$("option#London").change(function () {
    $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="country-list">
    <option value="" id="">select your city</option>
    <option value="London" id="London">London</option>
    <option value="CapeTown" id="CapeTown">Cape Town</option>
    <option value="Beijing" id="Beijing">Beijing</option>
    <option value="Tokyo" id="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
    <option value="HongKong" id="HongKong">Hong Kong</option>
    <option value="KualaLumpur" id="KualaLumpur">Kuala Lumpur</option>
    <option value="Singapore" id="Singapore">Singapore</option>
    <option value="Mumbai" id="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
    <option value="Shanghai" id="Shanghai">Shanghai</option>
    <option value="Sydney" id="Sydney">Sydney</option>
    <option value="StPetersburg" id="StPetersburg">St. Petersburg</option>
    <option value="SanPaulo" id="SanPaulo">São Paulo</option>
    <option value="SanFrancisco" id="SanFrancisco">San Francisco</option>
    <option value="Dallas" id="Dallas">Dallas</option>
    <option value="NewYork" id="NewYork">New York</option>
    <option value="Dubai" id="Dubai">Dubai</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ym4frmp6/

Comment: option elements don't generally fire click events, you should be using the change event on the select

Comment: You meant `$('#London')` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't: you can't listen to events on individual <option>s

Comment: originally is all wrapped on a span, and on mobile becomes a select option.

Comment: on my fiddle, please check it out

Comment: What is the actual aim, so that we can suggest better ways of doing this? Also What is the `#London` bookmark link supposed to do? Either the example is incomplete, or you may have duplicate IDs in your actual page.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie each option scrollTo a specific tag, but on click doesn't work

Comment: @user3699998 , http://jsfiddle.net/ym4frmp6/3/ This?

Comment: Stop using `click` events for `option`s. That may not even work across all browsers. Use `change` on the `select` instead.  @phillip100 has a nicer example

Comment: @phillip100 thanks dude put it on an answer please but, keeping the click event, how can change the function into yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **[`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event.

```
var body = $('html, body');

$('.country-list').on("change", function () {
    // make sure, the val() is not empty:
    if($(this).val()){
        body.animate({
            scrollTop: $('#'+$(this).val()).offset().top - 63
        }, 'slow');
    }

    return false;
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ym4frmp6/5/)

Comment: originally the click even is correctly working, but because I change the html dynamically, on select/option I have to change also the click event into a change event.

Comment: @user3699998 , you're listening to changes made on `select` element. You cannot listen on `option` click.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gago9osr/ please have a look at this, before, on desktop size, I need the click event!

Comment: @user3699998 , you **do not** need for a click event. Why would you? The problem with your demo is that you duplicates `id`'s (use `data-id` instead). look: http://jsfiddle.net/gago9osr/1/ Your `options` doesn't have to be identified.

Comment: @user3699998 , now I got your idea :-) You want the click event on `span` not the `option` http://jsfiddle.net/gago9osr/2/

Answer (score 2):

here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ym4frmp6/4/

```
$('.country-list').on("change", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selection = $(this).val();
    alert(selection);
});
```

the event is on change of the select, and you get the option value by calling `$(this).val()`

this solves the issue of the click event.

Comment: thanks, how can I keep the click function? and implement yours?

Comment: i guess what im saying is that you cant use the `.click()` on a select because the click even will trigger before you even select something (it'll trigger when you open the select in essence), you'll have to use this `.change()`, but you can put the rest of your general code for animation (if its functional) inside this change event and it'll work as you intended it to work

Comment: well, I'm nearly there but it doesn't scroll to the # section id ? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, I think it's simpler : (run it directly below)

```js
var $body = $('html,body'),
     $select = $('select.country-list');

$select.change(function (e) {   
    var aTag = $("a[name='"+ e.currentTarget.value +"']");
    $body.animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top - 40 },'slow');
});
```

```css
body{
    position: relative;
    height:100%;min-height:100%;
}

select{
    position: fixed;
}

a{
    display : block;
    margin-top : 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="country-list">
    <option value="">select your city</option>
    <option value="London" >London</option>
    <option value="CapeTown" >Cape Town</option>
    <option value="Beijing" >Beijing</option>
    <option value="Tokyo" >Tokyo</option>
    <option value="HongKong" >Hong Kong</option>
    <option value="KualaLumpur" >Kuala Lumpur</option>
    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
    <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
    <option value="Shanghai">Shanghai</option>
    <option value="Sydney">Sydney</option>
</select>
<br>
<a href="#" name="London">London</a><br>
<a href="#" name="CapeTown">CapeTown</a><br>
<a href="#" name="Beijing">Beijing</a><br>
<a href="#" name="Tokyo">Tokyo</a><br>
<a href="#" name="HongKong">HongKong</a><br>
<a href="#" name="KualaLumpur">KualaLumpur</a><br>
<a href="#" name="Singapore">Singapore</a><br>
<a href="#" name="Mumbai">Mumbai</a><br>
<a href="#" name="Shanghai">Shanghai</a><br>
<a href="#" name="Sydney">Sydney</a><br>
```

**Edit**

Changed `$select.find('option:selected').val()` into  `$(this).val()`. It works because the "select" elements takes the value from its selected "option".

**Edit 2**

Simplified again by changing `$(this).val()` into `e.currentTarget.value`.