# click() doesn't work with option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to target specific `option` by the option value, but seems that the click function doesn't work on `option` tags.

```
<select name="page_template" id="page_template">

    <option value="default">regular template</option>    
    <option value="page-templates/100-full-width.php">100% Full Width Page</option>
    <option value="templates/form-embed.php" selected="selected">Form Embed</option>
    <option value="page-templates/full-width.php">Full Width Page</option>
    <option value="templates/homepage.php">Homepage</option>

</select>
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('option[value="templates/form-embed.php"]').click(function(){
        //alert('test');
        $('.wp-editor-expand').toggleClass('hide');
    });

});
```

I want to check weather the option was clicked, regardless of weather it selected or not, as selected is set just after submitting the form.

Comment: You can't write a click event for option element. Write change event for the select element and detect the value change inside of it,.

Comment: It may just be me but your script is not in script tags :S

Comment: @avishay, pls do some research before posting questions. For simple questions like these you can find your answer online.

Comment: @KarthikMR You can find answer to almost every question online, the goal of this forum is to make things easier and save time researching. And  what simple for you don't necessary simple for other. Another thing, who told you I didn't search?

Comment: But these are old ones and already answered. Not enough research. It is duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368231/click-event-on-select-option-element-doesnt-work

Comment: @Avishay28 the goal of this forum is not to save time for researches but to share knowledge and solve specific issues:  It is not a "write code on my behalf". You have to show what you have tried and where you get stuck at. Your is a basic question that can be easilly solved with a google search. tool.

Comment: Have a look at the guidelines for asking questions in this forum. Basic criteria is your research effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Option` tag doesn't have **click** event handler, use `select`'s **change** event instead

```
$('#page_template').change(function(){
    if ( $(this).val() == "templates/form-embed.php" )
    {
       $('.wp-editor-expand').toggleClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this --

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#page_template').on('change',function(){
            if(this.value == "templates/form-embed.php"){
            alert('test');
            $('.wp-editor-expand').toggleClass('hide');
        }  
    });
});
```

Fiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/78e8xzq2/

Comment: for select it is better to use change than click