# How can we fire event on selected option when we select the selected option again

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

- when I select option '2' it opens bootstrap - modal.so the first time
  it opens modal.now option '2' is already selected. now again I click 
  on      option '2'. it doesn't fire any change event so, my bootstrap
  modal    doesn't open.because I wrote logic inside change
  event.
- so, how can I fire change event on selected option.

Comment: can you pls share what you had already done

Comment: You can use 'click' event as the 'change' will not get triggered for the selected option.

Comment: When you select "option 2" and change it to "option 2" there isn't a change at all, so the change event won't trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspite of `change` event trigger the modal on `click` event of `select option` like

```
$('select option').on('click',function(){
      $("#modelId").modal('show');
});
```

Comment: it seems that option element can not handle the click event. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368231/click-event-on-select-option-element-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2):

Create a select with a default value option.

```
<select id="slt">
    <option value="default">Select Something</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Every time, handle the change event for a not defaultValue option, and then reset the default option to selected.

```
var $slt = $('#slt'),
    defaultValue = 'default';

function handleChange(e){
    var val = $slt.val();

    // do nothing for defaultValue being selected
    if (val === defaultValue) {
        return;
    }

    // do something else
    console.log(val);

    // reset the value to defaultValue
    $slt.find('option:selected').prop('selected', false);
    $lst.find('option').eq(0).prop('selected', true);
}

$slt.bind('change', handleChange);
```

But this will make the select always show as "Select Something".

This is a demo about this: http://codepen.io/shuizhongyueming/pen/JWYYLJ

---

I found another solution for this, which is better than mine.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12404521/2279763

It use the `selectedIndex` to reset the selected value on focus, no need for the defaultValue option, and will show the the selected option after click.

This is the demo in the comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ecmanaut/335XK/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use modal function

```
$('select option').on('click'function(){
    $('modelId').modal('show');
});
```